# Include 0 to a annotate count if not found in django Queryset.?

Tags: django, matplotlib, django-models

I don't know how to phrase my question correctly but what I am doing is I am querying a table based on certain id and then getting the count of the unique field in a column and that count I am giving to matplotlib to plot but what problem I am facing is if a certain value is not found the label size mismatches with the count and plot doesn't work. Below is my query:

```
workshop_feedback = WorkshopFeedbackResponse.objects.filter(workshop_conducted=workshop_id)
count = workshop_feedback.values('q1').annotate(count=Count('q1'))
sizes = [item['count'] for item in count] #converting to list for matplotlib bar char
labels = [1,2,3] #option of choices for q1
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pie(sizes, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%',
       shadow=True, startangle=90)
ax.axis('equal')
# Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle.
plt.savefig(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, filename)) #filename is random image filename Which i am creating image of the graph
```

My column name is q1 and it can contain `1,2,3` as an option depending upon what user has filled but suppose if I don't have 1 or either option the count doesn't reflect that.

```
Exception Value:    
'label' must be of length 'x'
```

Above is the error I get from if count of certain value is missing. So How to get count as 0 if certain label value is missing?

Edit: If I can query based on label value to get count in a column I can fix my error.

Comment: Do you need to filter out the None's or have them be 0's?

Comment: I had a workaround, I will post my answer when I get time.